# Segfault in constructor with keyword this

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

**A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "B.h"

class A{
public:
    B* b;

A(){
    b->ownership = this;
};

};
#endif
```

**B.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A;

class B{
public:
    A* ownership;

};

#endif //B_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

class C{
    A a1;
    A a2;
};

int main()
{

    C c;

    return 0;

}
```

Commands:

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main
./main
```

This program fails with segmentation fault.
**"gdb main core"** told me that error was in string: **"b->ownership = this;"**

*Question: Where is my fault? What I should know not to make more of these errors? Thank you.*

Comment: The pointer `B*` was not initialized in A's constructor. It is pointing to undefined region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this class:

```
class A
{
public:
    B* b;

    A()
    {
        b->ownership = this;
    }
};
```

You're dereferencing `b` but you haven't created an instance of `B`.